# Doesn't get JavaScript RegEx to work

Tags: javascript, regex

Need help getting the following JavaScript RegEx case insensitive:

```
^(ABCDE)\d{5}$
```

I have tried `/i` but it doesn't work:

```
^(ABCDE)\d{5}$/i
```

Where should I place `/i` to get it to work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: ??? `/^(ABCDE)\d{5}$/i`. Show your code. Are you using a RegExp constructor? Then `var re = RegExp("^(ABCDE)[0-9]{5}$", "i")`

Comment: Sorry, I need to to approve both `ABCDE12345` and `abcde12345` (five digits). Both uppercase and lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a literal regex notation, just use `/.../`:

```
var re = /^(ABCDE)\d{5}$/i;
```

If you use a RegExp constructor:

```
var re = RegExp("^(ABCDE)[0-9]{5}$", "i");
```

However, the literal notation is preferable here since the pattern is constant, known from the beginning, and no variables are used to build it dynamically. Note that if you were to use `\d` in the `RegExp` constructor, you'd have to double the backslashes:

```
var re = RegExp("^(ABCDE)\\d{5}$", "i");
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried the first example. It doesn't work (first example) according to this site: http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html

Comment: It does work, you are using the site wrongly. Just use the option I circled red. In code, use what I provided above the image.

Comment: Just saw the picture. I need to try with the RegEx not the built in function on the site. I'll find another site or build my own script to test it. Thanks for the help mate.

Comment: Most SO people here believe (including me) the best site for testing JS, Python and PCRE regex is [regex101.com](http://regex101.com).

Answer (score 1):

Try to write it this way :

```
var regex = /^(ABCDE)\d{5}$/i;
```

It needs the first `/` or you can also use

```
var regex = new RegExp('^(ABCDE)\\d{5}$', 'i');
```

Then if you try in a console this it should work (online testers can add other issue, just try directly on your code) :

```
regex.test('ABCDE12345') // true
regex.test('abcde12345') // true
```

Test on Regex101 : https://regex101.com/r/zR5yR0/1

Comment: It doesn't work (first example) according to this site: http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html

Comment: By the way, if I can recommend you a website for regexes, I generally use https://regex101.com/